# using pd.to_numeric to handle bool dtype downcast into float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why the introduction of NA is changing the output of .to_numeric ? And how to handle bool dtype using to_numeric method in pandas ? Like for the first example below, i want all the output to be zero using pd.to_numeric.

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age':[False, False, False, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], errors='coerce',downcast = 'float')

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: Age, dtype: bool


data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age':[False, None, False, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], errors='coerce',downcast = 'float')
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    0.0
Name: Age, dtype: float32
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(float)
```

**The reason of your 2nd attempt can show float is because `NaN` values are already regarded as `float`.**  As the whole series is regarded as `object`, `pd.to_numeric()` can handle the conversion.  While for the 1st set of sample data where the data type is `bool`, `pd.to_numeric()` does not convert it.

Result:

For first set of sample data:

```
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

For second set of sample data:

```
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    0.0
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```